# Can a video embedded in PDF play when viewed in html

Tags: html, pdf, video

My Question is!

Can a video embedded in PDF play when viewed in html with whatever viewers(jquery/javascript/flash) available for viewing PDFs in HTML or HTML5...?

I have searched the internet and found no reference where these three elements are mentioned in one sentence!

Thank you.

Comment: A video in a PDF? Why, oh why?

Comment: Educational Purposes. We need to deliver content that has questions and answers and sometimes a form and answers with a video that provides the base for the questions and answers !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, as long as you have Adobe Reader installed. It looks like once you disable Chrome's default PDF reader, it will use Adobe Reader by default, which will give you all available options in the standalone reader.

I want to assume it's the same for all browsers, but a bit of Google Foo would tell you.

Source:
[Chrome's PDF Reader](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/1060734?hl=en)

Comment: You could also convert the PDF to HTML and view the video there (which improves the download permformance as the video is external to the main file). I did a comparison on our blog at http://blog.idrsolutions.com/2011/10/pdf-to-html5-conversion-video/

Comment: As of 2022, this is outdated, with the link declaring "Flash Player is no longer available"